# multiple comparison with controls - kruskall wallis or mann whitney + bonferroni

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, bonferroni

I have a test group and two control groups. I would like to compare:

test vs control group 1

test vs control group 2

and I don't need the result from control group 1 vs group 2. Therefore, in this case, should I use `Mann Whitney U` with $p$ x $2$ for `Bonferroni` correction or should I use `Kruskal Wallis` test?

Comment: I wonder about your lack of curiosity whether the two control groups differ. If the test group differs significantly from C1, but not from C2, will you claim a 'success'? Or are you hoping the test group differs signif from both C1 and C2? // You must have thought C1 & C2 differ in some way. Otherwise, why bother with both? // Is this for a protocol in advance of the study or have you already seen the data?

Comment: @bruceET, this is because the difference between the two control group was already quantified in a previous analysis, and the present analysis is just an extension to that. This is not protocoled in advance I have seen the data. I could do all the analysis together instead of separating into two parts but it would distrupt the story.

Comment: This reads like a standard ANOVA application.  Could you indicate how it differs?

Comment: @whuber the difference is that between these three sets of data, i am only interested to see the effect between two pairs of data instead of all three pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate post-hoc test for Kruskal-Wallis is Dunn (1964) test.  You could use Dunn test, look at only the comparisons you are interested in, and use a p-value correction † based on only those comparisons you are interested in.

There are other appropriate post-hoc tests.

The problem with using multiple Mann-Whitney tests is that each will be discarding information from the other groups. Results can be incommensurate or difficult to interpret. (See [Schwenk dice](https://www.futilitycloset.com/2018/06/27/schwenk-dice/).)

Dunn test essentially keeps the ranking of values from the original Kruskal-Wallis and avoids this problem. This is analogous to using pairwise t-tests with pooled variance from all groups. (See, for example, [how R conducts pairwise t-tests](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/pairwise.t.test).)

---

† In most cases, Bonferroni correction is overly conservative.  You might consider Holm, or [other methods used natively by R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html). See the Details section at that link for a list and very brief discussion.

Comment: I am using MATLAB instead of R and I am not clear about "use a p-value correction † based on only those p-value corrections you are interested in" what do you mean by interested in? In MATLAB, for eg, there will be only 1 p-value for each pair of test https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/multiple-comparisons.html

Comment: I wrote that slightly incorrectly.  I'll correct.  But I mean: You have three groups total, so if you looked at all comparisons, you would have three comparisons. If you were adjust alpha by Bonferroni, your corrected alpha would be 0.05 / 3 = 0.0167.  But you want to look at only two comparisons, so the alpha by Bonferroni would be 0.05 / 2 = 0.025.  You can ignore the comparison of Control 1 and Control 2 if that's what you want to do.

Comment: I see, the only thing is, see you see the link given above, in MATLAB, the correction is already performed in the function. therefore the P value is the corrected values already, assumingly according to the number of pairs

Comment: It's not clear to me what post-hoc test MatLab uses for Kruskal-Wallis.  But if the software is adjusting p-values with Bonferroni, it's pretty easy to reverse the correction.  If there are three comparisons, simply divide the reported p-values by 3 to get the uncorrected p-values.  Then you can adjust the two p-values you keep with Bonferroni by hand.  Or, if you would like to then use a different correction on the p-values you keep, you can run R online [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online), with e.g. this code: `Pvalues = c(0.002, 0.03); p.adjust(Pvalues, method="holm")`.